# error "Array to string conversion" en función array_diff_assoc() de php

Tags: php, php5

Creo 2 arrays con los mismos formato, y cuando los comparo con `array_diff_assoc()` me lanza el siguiente error:

> Array to string conversion

Código de como los creo:

```
$resultado = array_diff_assoc($arrayNuevos, $arrayViejos);
Debugbar::info($resultado);
```

El resultado (capturado con Debugbar) es el siguiente:

```html
<li class="phpdebugbar-widgets-list-item" style="cursor: pointer;">$arrayViejos: <span class="phpdebugbar-widgets-value phpdebugbar-widgets-info phpdebugbar-widgets-pretty"><pre class="language-php hljs "><code><span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">10</span> [
  <span class="hljs-number">0</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">2</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">1</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">3</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">2</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">13</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">3</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">32</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">4</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">14</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">5</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">25</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">6</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">26</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">7</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">15</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">8</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">30</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">9</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">31</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
  ]
]</code></pre></span></li>

<li class="phpdebugbar-widgets-list-item" style="cursor: pointer;">$arrayNuevos: <span class="phpdebugbar-widgets-value phpdebugbar-widgets-info phpdebugbar-widgets-pretty"><pre class="language-php hljs "><code><span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">10</span> [
  <span class="hljs-number">0</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">2</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">1</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">3</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">2</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">13</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">3</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">32</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">4</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">14</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">5</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">25</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">6</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">26</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">7</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">15</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">8</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">30</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
  <span class="hljs-number">9</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">array</span>:<span class="hljs-number">5</span> [
    <span class="hljs-string">"id"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-number">31</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"crear"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"editar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">true</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"eliminar"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
    <span class="hljs-string">"estado"</span> =&gt; <span class="hljs-keyword">false</span>
  ]
]</code></pre></span></li>
```

Hasta donde veo y entiendo tienen los mismos formatos.

¿Por que me lanza el error?

**OJO:** la creación del `array` no es el problema, puesto a que esta exactamente igual (refiriéndome a formato y no a valores internos de las asociaciones). Pueden ejecutar el código de prueba y verán los arrays en html bien ordenados.

Comment: en que linea muestra el error.?

Comment: Si no me equivoco array_diff() solo funciona para arreglos de una dimensión, y por lo que puedo apreciar tus arreglos son bidimensionales?

Comment: En realidad no he llegado a comprender ni lo que quieres hacer ni el problema que se está presentando. Pero viendo tu código, por algún motivo me da la impresión de que estás intentando reinventar la rueda. Pues creo que existen funciones para realizar cosas que, al parecer, intentas hacer manualmente. Por otra parte creo que cuando algo es **tan complicado** de entender, de plantear, de realizar ... hay **un error en otra parte: en la forma en que te estás planteando el problema**, dicho en otras palabras , puede que haya un error de lógica en cualquier parte.

Comment: @Victor-Random en la linea del @array_diff_assoc()

Comment: @Lixus si hermano, es bidimensional

Comment: Eh ahí el problema, `array_diff_assoc` solo funciona para arreglos de una dimensión, tendrías que buscar la manera de hacer tus arreglos o convertirlos a una sola dimensión

Comment: ok, gracias, indagare un rato en google acerca de eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano El error que tengo es en el `array_diff_assoc()`, los array estan bien hechos, como lo coloque en el ejemplo. La verdad no me se todos los nuevos metodos por eso lo hago a pulso ya que lo se hacer asi. Si hay otras maneras de hacerlo bienvenido sea.

Comment: [Aquí hay unas cuantas **ruedas** que ya existen](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php), creo que alguna puede ayudarte a resolver el problema. Anteriormente tenías a `array_diff_assoc ` como una función _tuya_, con código dentro, por eso dije lo de reinventar la rueda.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, voy a echarle un ojo a ver cuales uso.

Comment: Lee la nota de [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php). Dice: _Esta función sólo comprueba una dimensión de un array n-dimensional. Por supuesto, **se pueden comprobar arrays de más dimensiones usando, por ejemplo,_ `array_diff_assoc($array1[0], $array2[0]);`**.

Comment: @A.Cedano en eso estoy, hay funciones ya echas por programadores, para comparar 2 multi-dimensionales, estoy buscando aplicarlo al sistema.

Comment: A. Cedano la respuesta a la pregunta es como comento @Lixus primeramente, aunque los array que manejo no son `bidimensionales` sino `multidimensionales`. Acá el enlace de una funciona para comparar `arrays` multidimensionales: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php#73972. Si alguno formaliza la pregunta le doy la aprobación.

Comment: @A.Cedano aca tambien hay otra solucion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354767/use-array-diff-assoc-or-get-difference-of-multidimensional-arrays

PD: no se como colocar enlaces en los comentarios.

Comment: Pues listo, ya lo tienes. Para los enlaces sólo tienes que poner entre corchetes el texto visible y seguidamente entre paréntesis la url o link. Ejemplo: **[textovisible](url)** **no debes escribir espacios entre el último corchete y el primer paréntesis**.